# Align element to bottom corner inside a centered flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Bit of a mothful but to illustrate better I have these elements (note the Next link position not being in the corner):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  
  background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0cDOOJjp8pUGDDFLqHFITEi35uMGZ5wHpZ9KTKridxk71kpR9MfeydpQqG5n8Mvetvkg5iVuZGeL2xMvxgBY_UL-T9p0x_Eo4EAh);
  background-size: 80px 80px;
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container a{
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
  Lorem Ipsum<br>
  Lorem Ipsum
  <a href="/" class="button">Next</a>
</div>
```

And I want to order them in such way:

```
---------------------
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|      Welcome      |
|    Lorem Ipsum    |
|    Lorem Ipsum    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|              Next | 
|                   | 
---------------------
```

Such that **centered contents remain on the center** (regardless of height), **and** the **"Next"** **element is on the corner**, just as close to the image, but keeping a margin.

Any hacky solution is welcome, but **I highly prefer a solution that is relative for any display**, that's why I'm **not** relying on **absolute** positioning.

Comment: I just saw a CSS-tricks article on acieving this with display: grid. Try looking at the recent articles on their site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **short solution** that worked for me but in an specific case:
**If the view isn't scrollable** and/or remains fixed(e.g. `100vh` on `min-height`). Then **'absolute' positioning works fine** with the right units, see:

```css
button{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  padding: 0.4rem;
}
```

For other cases check other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin-top` but you have to use it on both the link and the body text so put the text in it's own `div` and you're sorted.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/0cDOOJjp8pUGDDFLqHFITEi35uMGZ5wHpZ9KTKridxk71kpR9MfeydpQqG5n8Mvetvkg5iVuZGeL2xMvxgBY_UL-T9p0x_Eo4EAh);
  background-size: 80px 80px;
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container div {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.link {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
    Lorem Ipsum<br> Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="link"><a href="/" class="button">Next</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works and might be the shortest answer, but if there is any other complex component/layout other fixes might be needed per case. Like components that don't inherit sizes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to position the Next button to the bottom of your container, simply add `margin-top: auto;` to `.container a` in your CSS. This will ensure the button always stays to the bottom of the container.

However, if you need to also make the content in the container be vertically centered, please try the below snippet instead. My solution to vertically center the inner content was to use `justify-content: center` on the inner child container, "**.item**", and set an explicit min-height (400px as an example).

I also made use of `flex-direction: column` for both the parent and child containers, so the content follows the flow that you outlined in your original post.

This method works fine for any screen size or any amount of text placed in the container and does not rely on absolute positioning.

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/selah_/pen/wvqzjqV

```css
body{
  background: slateblue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #fff;
}
        
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
        
.section__header {
  text-align: center;
}

.description{
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 2rem 2rem 2rem;  
}
```

```html
    <section class="container">
      <div class="item">
        <h1 class="title">Welcome!</h1>
            <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>           
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <a href="#">Next</a>
      </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: The problem with margin-top is everything else is pushed to the top. So now they aren't truly center-center. But it does solve the corner position

Comment: Ah okay, I see. My bad, I misunderstood and thought that all you wanted was the Next button to be in the bottom right corner. I have updated my answer to reflect what you want. Let me know if that works! Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/selah_/pen/wvqzjqV

Comment: So the solution is to set sizing on the inner child if I check correctly, however say <a> is replaced with a <button>, then the solution preferably would be to use margin rather than padding to position it correctly without visual problems. I appreciate the decoration but it might be confusing/bloating for other readers.

Comment: You can use <button> instead of <a> with no issues. ``justify-content: flex-end`` was used to position the Next link/button to the bottom right. Padding was just used to give it some spacing between the edges of the container. I have removed some of the decoration, but those were only put in place to make it easier to see the layout as you described it in your initial post. Other than that, I don't think there's much 'bloat' there to confuse anyone. Should be relatively simple to understand.